# Symfony2 - Removed FOS User Bundle manually and now cannot clear cache in production mode

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, production-environment, removeall, clear-cache

I installed FOS Userbundle to learn from it, but decided I didn't need it anymore. I then did the following to remove it. After removing, I ran composer update.

- removed the bundle from the vendor folder
- removed from the appKernel
- removed from the composer.json file
- removed the entity User.php file
- removed the settings from config.yml, security.yml, routing.yml

Now when I attempt to clear cache for production mode I get the following error below. Clearing cache in dev mode works fine.

Can show me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing to remove FOS User Bundle and be able to clear cache in production mode?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener' not found in /var/www/html/HealthFitness/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php on line 142

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/app/console:0

PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/app/console:27

PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121

PHP   4. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:86

PHP   5. appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2037

PHP   6. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService() /var/www/html/HealthFitness/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:343
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error indeed probably come from a cache error.

Have you this error executing `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` ?

You can else delete app/cache/prod/* manually.

Comment: What is the best way to delete app/cache/prod/* manually? And yes, the error came up after doing a cache:clear --env=prod.

Comment: Manually means `rm -rf app/cache/prod/*` ;) This don't affect acl and let apache rights to the folder prod/

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't remove the files manually this should work as well.

You could also use a `--no-warmup` and `--no-optional-warmers` switches:

`cache:clear --no-warmup --no-optional-warmers --env=prod`

that way it should not try to recreate the cache of non existing classes and then do a

`cache:warmup --env=prod`

Manually removing cache is faster though, but you still warm it up.